# How to get variable value out side from the rest call method in Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am implementing one directive and In the directive I am calling one rest call then getting some data. So I am storing one value in variable and I want to put variable value in the return statement directive.

**I am sharing code**
***work.js***

```
angular.module('Smart.Form').directive('changeWrok', function (Rh) {
  Rh.one('/test/work').one('app').one('profiles').get().then(function (response) {
    var setValue = response['value-engine'];      // in setValue(like 4 or 5 or 7)  
  });


  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    // replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'app/plain/directives/change-work.tpl.html',
    link: function (scope, form) {
      form.bootstrapValidator({
        row: {
          valid: 'field-success',
          invalid: 'field-error'
        },
        fields: {
          riskScore: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'integer is required'
              },
              greaterThan: {
                value: setValue,
                message: "integer should be positive"
              }
            }
          },
          radioRiskGroup: {
            validators: {
              notEmpty: {
                message: 'Risk Group is required'
              }
            }
          },

        }
      });

     }
    }
  }
});
```

In the Rh.one setValue  is coming, But I am not able to get outside. I also tried $scope.setValue, But this directive is not works. some error will come in console. SO I want to set setValue value in return statement.

> value: setValue,
>   after calling restcall setValueshould set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you place the REST call inside the directives controller, so you bind `setValue` to the local scope :

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'app/plain/directives/change-work.tpl.html',
  controller: function($scope, Rh) {
    Rh.one('/test/work').one('app').one('profiles').get().then(function (response) {
      $scope.setValue = response['value-engine']; 
    })
  },
  link: function(scope, form) {
    ...
              greaterThan: {
                value: scope.setValue, //<-----
                message: "integer should be positive"
              }
    ...
  }
}
```